# how can we automatically add commas to numbers being typed in SPFx react fluent textfield. ex: 1,000,000,000

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, reactjs, fluent-ui

```
<div>
   <TextField
      value={this.state.Budget}
      onChanged={this.onChangeBudget}
   />
</div> 

public onChangeBudget = (value: string) => {
   console.log("Budget : " + value);
   console.log(value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ','));
   let abc = value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
   return this.setState({ Budget: abc });
}
```

So the issue is when I am logging the value its showing correct result(1,111,111,111). But when I am doing the `setState` for the same, it is shows the result like this (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,111).

Please suggest where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My test code for your reference:

```
public onChangeBudget = (value: string) => {
    
    let newValue=value.replace(/,/g, "");
   
    let abc = newValue.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
    return this.setState({ Budget: abc });
 }
```

Test result:
[image]